# Display custom success or error progress bar

Tags: django, progress-bar

I am making a django app that displays a [progress bar](https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/). So far I have got it working to display a progress bar using this [library](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress) and the following code which they suggested.

```
  <div class='progress-wrapper'>
<div id='progress-bar' class='progress-bar' style="background-color: #68a9ef; width:      
0%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar-message">Waiting for progress to start...</div>
<script src="{% static 'celery_progress/celery_progress.js' %}"></script>
<script>
// vanilla JS version
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
var progressUrl =
                "{%
                   try:
 url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id
 catch:
      pprint("PHEW")
 %}";
 CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl);

  });
   </script>
```

However, how might i integrate the above code with the code below to get it to display [success or error](https://buildwithdjango.com/projects/celery-progress/):

```
  function customSuccess(progressBarElement, progressBarMessageElement) {
   progressBarElement.innerHTML = (
   '<figure class="image"><img src="/static/projects/images/aww-yeah.jpg"></figure>'
   )
   progressBarElement.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
   progressBarMessageElement.innerHTML = 'success!'
   }
   function customError(progressBarElement, progressBarMessageElement) {
   progressBarElement.innerHTML = (
   '<figure class="image"><img src="/static/projects/images/okay-guy.jpg"></figure>'
   )
   progressBarElement.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
   progressBarMessageElement.innerHTML = 'shucks.'
   }
  CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(taskUrl, {
  onSuccess: customSuccess,
  onError: customError,  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the script in your html with this one:

```
    <script>



   function customSuccess(progressBarElement, 
   progressBarMessageElement) {
    progressBarElement.innerHTML = (
     '<figure class="image"><img src="/static/projects/images/aww-yeah.jpg"></figure>'
    )
    progressBarElement.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    progressBarMessageElement.innerHTML = 'success!'
}
function customError(progressBarElement, progressBarMessageElement) {
    progressBarElement.innerHTML = (
     '<figure class="image"><img src="/static/projects/images/okay-guy.jpg"></figure>'
    )
    progressBarElement.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    progressBarMessageElement.innerHTML = 'shucks.'
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";
    CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl, {
        onSuccess: customSuccess,
        onError: customError,
    });
});

</script>
```

i tried it with the same app. it works!  :)

don't forget to change this one to a valid url:

```
<img src="/static/projects/images/aww-yeah.jpg">)
```